# Finding a maximal ideal and a prime ideal in $\mathbb Z_8[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> $1.$ Find a maximal ideal and a prime ideal in $\mathbb Z_8[x]$

**Attempt:**  Finding a maximal ideal, I am not sure how do I go about it. $\mathbb Z_8[x]$ is not a $PID$, so there's no use finding an irreducible polynomial as well.

**EDIT:**   I am trying to show $2$ must be in all prime/maximal ideals

What should be the logical procedure in actually trying to find out a maximal ideal in any ring?

> $2.$ Let $R=\{a/b~~|~~a,b \in \mathbb Z, 3 \nmid b\}$ . We need to find it's field of quotients.

**Attempt:** $R$ can be verified to be an integral domain, so, there exists a field $F$ called the field of quotients of $R$ which has a subring isomorphic to $D$

$R$ is not a field as $3/2$ is not invertible in $R$.

Let $p,q \in R$. Then let $p/q$ denote the equivalence class containing $(p,q)$

Then define $p/q + r/s = ps+rq/qs$ and $p/q \cdot r/s =pr/qs$

The set of these quotients form a field isomorphic to the set of rational whose denominators are not a multiple of $3$.

Am I correct?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The ideal generated by $x$ is not prime, because the quotient ring is $\mathbb{Z}_8$ which is not a domain. Finding a maximal ideal in a general ring (commutative or not) requires the axiom of choice.

Comment: Ohh my bad. Removing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lots of questions here, so I'll focus on just one of them.  One way of finding a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}_8[x]$ is using the fact that an ideal $I$ is maximal if and only if $\mathbb{Z}_8[x]/I$ is a field.

First, recognize that $\mathbb{Z}_8/\langle 2 \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$, and so it follows that $\mathbb{Z}_8[x]/\langle 2 \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}_2[x]$.  What are the maximal ideals in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$?  The corresponding maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}_8[x]$?  Hint: The latter won't be principal.

I should add that all maximal ideals are prime ideals, so you've really answered two questions if you can answer this one.

**Edit**: If you wish to find an ideal that is prime, but *not* maximal, then apply the fact that an ideal $I$ in a ring $R$ is prime $\iff$ $R/I$ is an integral domain.  Another hint for approaching this: $R/I$ cannot be finite since all finite integral domains are fields.

Comment: I think $\langle x \rangle$ should be a maximal ideal in $\mathbb Z_2[x]$ since $x$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z_2[x]$. Now, need to find the corresponding maximal ideal in $\mathbb Z_8[x]$.

Comment: Ok, there we go. It's maximal because $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/\langle x \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ is a field.  Now how can we get $\mathbb{Z}_2$ from $\mathbb{Z}_8[x]$?

Comment: By defining a mapping $\Psi: \mathbb Z_8[x] \rightarrow \mathbb Z_2[x]$ s.t. $\Psi (f(x)) = a_n \mod 2 $ where $a_n$ is the leading coefficient of $f(x)$

Comment: I think you mean $\phi:\mathbb{Z}_8[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2$.  I see where you're trying to go, but that won't work because your $\phi$ isn't a homomorphism.  In particular, $\phi(f(x) + g(x)) = \phi(f(x)) + \phi(g(x))$ isn't always satisfied.  If you can think of such a homomorphism, that's great, and you can do it that way!  What I'm actually trying to get at here is that, if you have an ideal of a ring $R$ generated by, say $x$, and another ideal generated by $y$, then $(R/\langle x \rangle)/ \langle y \rangle \cong R/ \langle x, y \rangle$.

Comment: I get totally what you said above. But, I am not able to relate to our requirements.

Comment: Well, an ideal $I$ of a ring $R$ is maximal $\iff$ $R/I$ is a field.  We're looking for an ideal to mod out $\mathbb{Z}_8[x]$ by so that we end up with a field, which we're taking to be $\mathbb{Z}_2$ in this case.

Comment: True .. my source of confusion is : $\mathbb Z_8[x]/ \langle 2 \rangle \approx \mathbb Z_2[x]$ which however is not a field.. it's an integral domain and a principal ideal domain though

Comment: Well that's one part of your question answered.  Read the last paragraph of my original response.  Now how can we manipulate $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ to convert it into a field?  When you have an answer, think back to the last sentence of my second comment.

Comment: Okay .. So, I think we have a prime ideal which is $\langle 2 \rangle[x]$ in $\mathbb Z_8[x]$ . The next task is to find the maximal ideal. We found out that $\langle x \rangle$ is a maximal ideal in $\mathbb Z_2[x]~;~ \mathbb Z_2[x]/ \langle x \rangle \approx \mathbb Z_2$ which is a Field.

I believe I should now proceed in this direction further

Comment: Yeah, that's good.  I'm slightly confused by notation, but the ideal generated by $2$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}_8[x]$ as I think you're saying.  To find a maximal ideal, apply the fact that $(R/\langle x \rangle)/\langle y \rangle \cong R/ \langle x, y \rangle$.  You're very close.

Comment: Yeah,I meant the ideal generated by $2$ in $\mathbb Z_8[x]. 

(\mathbb Z_8[x]/\langle 2 \rangle)/\langle x \rangle) \approx \mathbb Z_8[x]/\langle 2,x \rangle $


$\implies \mathbb Z_2  \approx \mathbb Z_8[x]/\langle 2,x \rangle$. Is that it?

Comment: which means $\langle 2,x \rangle $ is the required maximal ideal?

Comment: Yep, you got it.

Comment: Thank you so much Kaj :-). I did not have this result in my mind : $(R/\langle x \rangle)/\langle y \rangle \approx R/\langle x,y \rangle$ but now think this is such an important one to mod out elements

Comment: I'm glad I could help!  Best of luck with the last part of your question.  My ring theory is kind of rusty, and I want to avoid embarrassing myself.  I think there are far more qualified people to help you out there.  :P

Comment: Haha Alright. I will figure that out as well :-)

Answer (score 5):

Hint for #1. Show that $2$ must be in all prime ideals. Also convince yourself of the fact that $\Bbb{Z}_8[x]/\langle 2\rangle\cong\Bbb{Z}_2[x]$. Can you find prime ideals/maximal ideals in the latter ring, and pull them back to the original ring?

Hint for #2. Can you think of a field that contains $R$? What is the smallest such field? Can you show that it is the field of quotients of $R$.

Comment: uhmm.. If $R$ is a commutative ring and $I$ is an ideal of $R$, then $R[x]/I[x] \approx (R/I)[x]$. Since $Z_8/ \langle 2 \rangle \approx Z_2 \implies Z_8[x]/ \langle 2 \rangle \approx Z_2[x]$ .So, the first part of the hint is done.

Since $Z_2[x]$ is principal ideal domain, $\implies $ it suffices to find any irreducible polynomial in $Z_2[x]$. $x$ is such a polynomial? Hence $\langle x \rangle$ is a maximal ideal in $Z_2[x]$ . Am I on the correct path?

for (2), the smallest field containing $R$ is $\mathbb Q$. But, I am confused due to the condition that the $3$ does not divide denominator?

Comment: Looks good for part one (what's the preimage of that prime ideal in $\Bbb{Z}_8[x]$?). Can you write all the elements of $\Bbb{Q}$ as fractions with numerator and denominator both from $R$?

Comment: Sorry, I am stuck on finding the pre image of the ideal in $\mathbb Z_8[x]$

uhm, yeah, I think so. We can write all elements of $\mathbb Q$ using elements from $R$.

Comment: Is the pre image $\langle 3x \rangle$?

Comment: As Kaj Hansen hinted, the preimage is not a principal ideal. Remember that $2$ mapsto zero, so it is in the preimage, too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I finally got it. I was probably missing an important result $(R/\langle x \rangle)/\langle y \rangle \approx R/\langle x,y \rangle$ which led to the answer :-)

Comment: Well done, @VHP!